# What is the correct LinkedIn page cover image size?

Tags: linkedin, images, photos, html

I checked the size guide for LinkedIn cover images [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/70781/image-specifications-for-your-linkedin-pages-and-career-pages?lang=en)

For page, they say:

```
1192 (w) x 220 (h) pixels (min)

1536 (w) x 768 (h) pixels (recommended)
```

**Doubt 1:** Both have different ratios. Why is that?

**Doubt 2:** When I opened developer tools, I found the dimensions of the image container as 1128x191px. **Which also has a ratio different to them**.

**So what is the correct ratio for the cover? And why the ratio differs in developer tools and normal guidelines**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn, as well as other major websites, can't afford to lock down aspect ratio to a specific variable due to cross-platform support of various devices and browsers.

Therefore, correct LinkedIn Page Cover should be between 1192-1536 px for width and 220-768 px height or in aspect ratio notation: between 298:55 - 2:1 (with respect to max/min resolution of course).

After uploading such an image (eg. based on right dimension guidelines), the image is processed by an internal tool which will either create pre-defined versions of the image for different scenarios and store them on server side ready to be called by the browser, or this tool is implemented and does its magic in real time.